# No Saxophone part in band sheet music

Tags: sheet-music, orchestra, saxophone, band

I am attempting to have my band/orchestra students learn a song for our holiday concert, but the song doesn't have a saxophone part. Which other instrument part could I have my saxophone players join in on that doesn't require a lot of transposing. I am a violinist so this is very new for me.

Comment: Can you give us a list of the instruments featured in your Arrangement (and maybe also one of the instruments your studends have available)? Alto/Baritone-Saxophone can do any sort of Eb-Instrument without transposing, soprano/tenor can take the part of Bb-Instruments (of which there are more options).

Comment: One shortcut is to have them read any bass clef part as if it was treble clef and add three sharps.  If there aren't many accidentals it's a good trick to know.  Example: cello part in key of D has A on the top line.  Saxophone players can pretend it's in treble clef, key of B, and play F# on the top line.

Comment: @nuggethead That only works for E-flat saxophones, and only baritones sax ends up in the right octave (bass parts played on an alto would probably sound very odd)..

Comment: Yes @PiedPiper you are correct.

Comment: @nuggethead: I just commented that on an answer and then realized it was here already, and also PiedPiper's observation about orchestration.  Late to the party! Lindsey: you might also take the opportunity to introduce the concept of movable clefs.  I've always found that the easiest way to approach transposition - I imagine a movable clef that points at whatever line or space I need to be C (or G).

Answer (score 1):

For starters, there are two 'keys' that saxes play in. I say 'keys' as they are transposing instruments, and, yes, of course, they play in every conceivable key, but their dots need to reflect the fact that they are *transposing* instruments.

This means they don't read concert pitch, but compensated parts. Mostly you'll have alto saxes, transposing from E♭. and tenors, which transpose from B♭.

Consequentially, some of the parts you already have in your orchs are readily available! Those specifically being trumpet and clarinet sections, which will be written transposed for B♭ instruments. Making it easy for the tenors to play the trumpet/clarinet parts. Albeit an octave lower.

E♭? Bit more difficult. I think you're going to have to transcribe some other parts. There may be other horn parts they could play, but I think that's going to be a far cry.

Comment: Unless the absence of saxophone parts is related to the age of the arrangement, in which case there may be E-flat clarinet or cornet parts.

Comment: There is sometimes an E♭ horn part, but in my experience it is oompah accompaniment, very boring for saxes, who are used to playing an actual melody.

Answer (score 0):

Alto or Tenor saxophone?  You can give a B♭ Tenor sax a Trumpet or Clarinet part, though it might be more musically useful doubling Trombone, which will require transposing and maybe some adjustment of the lowest notes  (but hey! no pain no gain...)
E♭ Alto sax could also take the Trumpet part, but will certainly need transposing.

I'm afraid running a band often means YOU putting in just as much work as the students. :-)

Comment: Given how much the typical band-student works, it would be a dream job if the director only had to work that much! :-)